# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.custom_post'

Tags: django, pycharm, rename, wsgi

Using django and Pycharm. I am getting the above error when I try to run the server. I have searched everywhere in my code and I dont see the module named `custom_post` anywhere.

At one point I created an app named `messages`. I then noticed that this already exists in django, so I renamed it (using Pycharm) `custom_post`. At which point i started getting WSGI errors, so I reverted back to a previous commit that had the app named `messages` (vs. `custom_post`), and deleted the `messages` app. Now here I am.

I am not even sure which files to show you guys. I think when I refactored from "messages" to "custom_post" is changed something and I cant figure out what. Any guidance is great.

Traceback, hopefully someone finds this helpful:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'django.contrib.custom_post'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.contrib.custom_post'
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked, 
line 953
Python Executable:   
/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',


'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/
python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 29 Nov 2018 03:49:58 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view


/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/ 
python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars


/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/ 
python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py in __call__
            response = self.process_request(request) ...
▶ Local vars


/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/
python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/middleware.py in 
process_request
        request._messages = default_storage(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/__init__.py in default_storage
    return import_string(settings.MESSAGE_STORAGE)(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _gcd_import
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _call_with_frames_removed
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _gcd_import
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _call_with_frames_removed
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _gcd_import
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
<frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked
<source code not available> ...
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
ryan0000

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'gEkYo889p8d0S3LR9VFryz098cV47u1QaISCPtjrfoeK0MSkB2lxvJzkL8hm7iu3'
sessionid   
'r6u51pkf0cphybb3j78lk6babd2d3489'
META
Variable    Value
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render  
'/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.AkqaraMjtl/Render'
COMMAND_MODE    
'unix2003'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'gEkYo889p8d0S3LR9VFryz098cV47u1QaISCPtjrfoeK0MSkB2lxvJzkL8hm7iu3'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'vicarious.settings'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
HOME    
'/Users/X'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.9'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('csrftoken=gEkYo889p8d0S3LR9VFryz098cV47u1QaISCPtjrfoeK0MSkB2lxvJzkL8hm7iu3; '
 'sessionid=r6u51pkf0cphybb3j78lk6babd2d3489')
HTTP_HOST   
'127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
 'like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36')
LC_CTYPE    
'en_US.UTF-8'
LOGNAME 
'X'
PATH    
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
PATH_INFO   
'/'
PS1 
'(vicarious_env) \\h:\\W \\u\\$ '
PWD 
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SECURITYSESSIONID   
'186a7'
SERVER_NAME 
'1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
SHLVL   
'1'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   
'/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.m6fZ2ZwMh7/Listeners'
TERM    
'xterm-256color'
TMPDIR  
'/var/folders/gq/bj63_47d7c73vwq61gcywg7m0000gn/T/'
TZ  
'UTC'
USER    
'X'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR  
'/Users/X/virtualenvs'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME  
'.project'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT    
'/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD 
'1'
VIRTUAL_ENV 
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env'
WORKON_HOME 
'/Users/X/virtualenvs'
XPC_FLAGS   
'0x0'
XPC_SERVICE_NAME    
'0'
_   
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/bin/python'
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING 
'0x1F5:0x0:0x0'
__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__ 
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/vicarious_env/bin/python'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
wsgi.input  
<_io.BufferedReader name=6>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module vicarious.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
'/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': '/Users/X/Documents/Pycharm_Coding/vicarious/db.sqlite3',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'event']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
MEDIA_URL   
''
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.custom_post.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'vicarious.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'vicarious.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
[]
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_ETAGS   
False
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'vicarious.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

Comment: somewhere in your code, you changed `from django.contrib.messages` which is the message framework of Django, to `custom_post`. In case `messages` framework is used in your project, then you will need to replace back all the `custom_post`

Comment: i searched the entire code for the words `custom_post` and got nothing. not sure how else to find it...